# Unable to mock with Quarkus, NullPointer exception and cannot find relevant imports

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, quarkus

I am trying to write unit tests for Quarkus using Mockito, but I fail mocking things.

Here is a minimal (not) working example :

```
package com.my.package;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@QuarkusTest
public class LoadCalculatorServiceTest {

    public class Foobar {
        public int baz;
        public void setBaz(int baz) {
            this.baz = baz;
        }
        public int getBaz() {
            return this.baz;
        }
    }

    @Mock
    Foobar foobar;
    // Foobar foobar = new Foobar(); // doesn’t work either

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Mockito.when(foobar.getBaz()).thenReturn(4); // NullPointer
        Assertions.assertEquals(4,foobar.getBaz());
    }
}
```

The test crashes on a NullPointer.

I read such issues may be fixed by annotating the test with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` (which for some reason I expected `@QuarkusTest` to do anyway ?), however I fail to find the correct imports to load them.

I tried `org.junit.jupiter.api.MockitoExtension`, `org.junit.runner.RunWith` and variations, without success.

Here is the relevant part of my `pom.xml` :

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Maybe @Mock Foobar foobar; ? ... w/o new

Comment: @J.Doe Actually it was already an attempt to remove the error, I already tried your suggestion (which is what is found in most tutorials).  Question edited with it.

Answer (score 6):

I figured **the original code works with plain-style mocks :**

```
Foobar foobar = Mockito.mock(Foobar.class);
```

So the question is actually *how to make the `@Mock` annotation work ?*  There are several things needed for that :

1. The `@RunWith` annotation has been replaced (or should we say *upgraded*) by `@ExtendWith` in JUnit5.  It can be imported in Quarkus using `import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;`.
2. `@RunWith` is usually used as `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.  MockitoExtension can be imported in Quarkus using `import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;`.  **Beware** that the `mockito-junit-jupiter` dependency (from the `org.mockito` group) must be added to the `pom.xml`, since the `quarkus-junit5-mockito` packages [do not depend on it](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/11361).
3. Mocks have to be initialized by `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` before the tests.  Note that although it may seem to make more sense to use `@BeforeAll` for the setup function, apparently it is not the point of this annotation and one should use `@BeforeEach` (the former needs the setup to be static, and IIUC the setup function will be called before each test anyway).
4. Then finally the `@Mock` annotation should work.

To summarize, the original code would become :

```
package com.my.package;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@QuarkusTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class LoadCalculatorServiceTest {

    public class Foobar {
        public int baz;
        public void setBaz(int baz) {
            this.baz = baz;
        }
        public int getBaz() {
            return this.baz;
        }
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Mock
    Foobar foobar;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Mockito.when(foobar.getBaz()).thenReturn(4);
        Assertions.assertEquals(4,foobar.getBaz());
    }
}
```

with the following addition to the `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using quarkus 1.8.1.Final, with mockito 3.6.0, I had the same issue with @Mock annotation and I followed the answer from [Skippy le Grand Gourou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812102/skippy-le-grand-gourou) and it didn't work, so I deleted the @QuarkusTest annotation, and delete de  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) method, my mockito version has deprecated this, then the test run with the @Mock annotation. I'm new doing Quarkus so I don't know very well the side effects of removing @QuarkusTest

Comment: Removing @QuarkusTest will have impact on all non-unit test, where you need the Quarkus IoC features.